# In Django how can I add the id in the slug title

Tags: python, django

How can I add the id in the slug so that it will appear like this

> "this-is-a-deal-1"

where "this is a deal" is the title and "1" is the id number. At the moment with the current code it is appearing as `"this-is-a-deal-None"`

models.py
    ... 
    slug = models.SlugField()

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            # Newly created object, so set slug
            self.slug = '%s-%s' %(
                            slugify(self.deal_title),
                            str(self.id))
```

views.py

```
def deal_page(request, deal_title_slug):

    # Create a context dictionary which we can pass to the template rendering engine.
    context_dict = {}

    try:
        deal = SubmitDeal.objects.get(slug=deal_title_slug)
        context_dict['deal_title'] = deal.deal_title

        context_dict['deal'] = deal
    except SubmitDeal.DoesNotExist:
        # We get here if we didn't find the specified category.
        # Don't do anything - the template displays the "no category" message for us.
        pass

    return render(request, 'deal_page.html', context_dict)
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^(?P<deal_title_slug>[\w\-]+)/$', 'submit_deals.views.deal_page', name='deal_page'),
```

admin.py

```
class SubmitModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug':('deal_title',)} #prepopulate slug with deal_title
    class meta:
        model = SubmitDeal

admin.site.register(SubmitDeal, SubmitModelAdmin)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't alter the slug in the db.  Separate the `slug` and `id` in the url:

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w\-]+)-(?P<pk>\d+)/$', 'submit_deals.views.deal_page',
                                         name='deal_page'),
```

An then use `pk` to get the object and ignore the `slug`:

```
def deal_page(request, slug, pk):
    try:
        deal = SubmitDeal.objects.get(pk=pk)
        context_dict = {'deal_title': deal.deal_title, 'deal': deal}
    except SubmitDeal.DoesNotExist:
        context_dict = {}
   return render(request, 'deal_page.html', context_dict)
```